# ASP.NET C# Sql Join a Time range without duplicating [asp.net cleansing]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the below two tables

**MBA**

```
+--------+----------+------------+--------------+------------------+------------+
|mbaId   |  Channel | Product    |  ProgDate    |   ProgStartTime  |ProgEndTime |
+--------+----------+ -----------+--------------+------------------+------------+
|12      |    AA    |     SS     |  01/04/2011  |    16:00:00      |  20:00:00  |
|13      |    AA    |     SS     |  01/04/2011  |    16:00:00      |  20:00:00  |
|14      |    AA    |     SS     |  01/04/2011  |    16:00:00      |  20:00:00  | 
|15      |    AA    |     SS     |  01/04/2011  |    17:00:00      |  18:00:00  |
+--------+----------+------------+--------------+------------------+------------+
```

**MAP**

```
+----------+--------+---------------+-------------------+---------+----+
|mapId     |Channel | Product       |ProgDate           |  AdvTime|    |        
+----------+--------+---------------+-------------------+---------+----+    
|8         | AA     | SS            | 01/04/2011        | 19:35:14| 30 |
|9         | AA     | SS            | 01/04/2011        | 18:40:19| 27 |
|10        | AA     | SS            | 01/04/2011        | 19:36:58| 35 |
|11        | AA     | SS            | 01/04/2011        | 17:47:13| 28 |
+----------+--------+---------------+-------------------+---------+----+
```

**I would require the below output**

```
+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+---------+--------------+-----------+-----+
| mapId     |Channel|Product| ProgDate    | AdvTime |ProgStartTime |ProgEndTime|mbaid| 
+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+---------+--------------+-----------+-----+
|  8        | AA    | SS    | 01/04/2011  | 19:35:14|16:00:00      | 20:00:00  |  12 |  
|  9        | AA    | SS    | 01/04/2011  | 18:40:19|16:00:00      | 20:00:00  |  13 | 
|  10       | AA    | SS    | 01/04/2011  | 19:36:58|16:00:00      | 20:00:00  |  14 | 
|  11       | AA    | SS    | 01/04/2011  | 17:47:13|16:00:00      | 17:00:00  |  15 | 
+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+---------+--------------+-----------+-----+
```

**I use the below code**

```
select *
from MBA2 as mba
  inner join Map2 as map on(map.Channel=mba.Channel and map.Product=mba.Product)
    where(
    (MBA.ProgStartTime < MBA.ProgEndTime
      and MBA.ProgStartTime <=
        case when datediff(mi, MBA.ProgStartTime, MBA.ProgEndTime) <= 60
          then dateadd(mi, 5, Map.AdvTime)
          else Map.AdvTime
          end
      and MBA.ProgEndTime >=
        case when datediff(mi, MBA.ProgStartTime, MBA.ProgEndTime) <= 60
          then dateadd(mi, -5, Map.AdvTime)
          else Map.AdvTime
          end) or
    (MBA.ProgStartTime > MBA.ProgEndTime
      and (MBA.ProgStartTime <=
        case when 1440 - datediff(mi, MBA.ProgEndTime, MBA.ProgStartTime) <= 60
          then dateadd(mi, 5, Map.AdvTime)
          else Map.AdvTime
          end
      or MBA.ProgEndTime >=
        case when 1440 - datediff(mi, MBA.ProgEndTime, MBA.ProgStartTime) <= 60
          then dateadd(mi, -5, Map.AdvTime)
          else Map.AdvTime
          end)))
order by advtime asc
```

But i get duplicates i.e the value 19:35:14 matches the range 16:00:00 to 20:00:00 for the ids 12,13 and 14. I need one value in MAP match one value in MBA.

SO i used the below code to add data into a dataset and find the duplicates in MAPID

```
if (repeatID.Contains(int.Parse(dr["mapID"].ToString())))
        {
            duplicateID.Add(int.Parse(dr["mapID"].ToString()));


        }

        else
        {
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1[0] = int.Parse(dr["mapID"].ToString());

            dr1[10] = int.Parse(dr["mbaID"].ToString());

            dr1[1] = (dr["Channel"].ToString());


            dr1[2] = (dr["Product"].ToString());


            dr1[3] = (dr["ProgDate"].ToString());


            dr1[4] = (dr["AdvTime"].ToString());


            dr1[5] = (dr["Progstarttime"].ToString());


            dr1[6] = (dr["Progendtime"].ToString());


            dr1[7] = (dr["Channel"].ToString());

            dr1[8] = (dr["Product"].ToString());

            dr1[9] = (dr["ProgDate"].ToString());




            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

        }

        repeatID.Add(int.Parse(dr["mapID"].ToString()));

       i = i + 1;
    }
    sCon.Close();
}
```

And remove the repeating id row. Then use the below query to display the data without duplicates and again to datatable. It returns without duplicate mapid in datatable but with MBAID Dulicates.

```
using (SqlConnection sCon = new SqlConnection(connec))
        {

            foreach (int id in duplicateID)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow ddr = dt.Rows[i];
                    if (ddr["mapID"].ToString() == id.ToString())
                        ddr.Delete();
                }


                sCon.Open();
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select Distinct top 1 mp.Id as mapid, mb.Id as mbaid, mp.Channel, mp.Product, mp.ProgDate, mp.AdvTime, mb.Channel,  mb.ProgStartTime,mb.ProgEndTime,mb.progdate, convert(time, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, mb.progStartTime, mb.progEndTime), 0)) as timeDiff 
from MBA22 as mb
  inner join Map22 as mp on(mp.Channel=mb.Channel and mp.Product=mb.Product and mb.ProgDate=mp.ProgDate )
    where(
    (mb.ProgStartTime < mb.ProgEndTime
      and mb.ProgStartTime <=
        case when datediff(mi, mb.ProgStartTime, mb.ProgEndTime) <= 60
          then dateadd(mi, 5, mp.AdvTime)
          else mp.AdvTime
          end
      and mb.ProgEndTime >=
        case when datediff(mi, mb.ProgStartTime, mb.ProgEndTime) <= 60
          then dateadd(mi, -5, mp.AdvTime)
          else mp.AdvTime
          end) or
    (mb.ProgStartTime > mb.ProgEndTime
      and (mb.ProgStartTime <=
        case when 1440 - datediff(mi, mb.ProgEndTime, mb.ProgStartTime) <= 60
          then dateadd(mi, 5, mp.AdvTime)
          else mp.AdvTime
          end
      or mb.ProgEndTime >=
        case when 1440 - datediff(mi, mb.ProgEndTime, mb.ProgStartTime) <= 60
          then dateadd(mi, -5, mp.AdvTime)
          else mp.AdvTime
          end)))
and mp.Id = '" + id + "'  order by  timeDiff asc", sCon);
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

PLEASE HELPPPP

Comment: You will either have to add MBAId in MAP table or MAPId in MBA table. And join using it.

Comment: @RaviSingh

But i dont have any foreign key relationship within the tables

Comment: ok it is a little bit confusing the way you have set the question. As I understand you need a one map for one mba without repeating the advertising time/ map right?

Comment: @TonyShih

Exactly . An AdvTime mapped for one StartTime EndTime shouldnt be duplicated[as my expected output suggests]

Answer (score 0):

Try this query works accordingly but is risky as according to your need 1 record maps to another table so the sequence should be properly maintained else you will get wrong records

```
select 
    t2.mapId, 
    t1.Channel, 
    t1.Product, 
    t1.ProgDate, 
    t2.AdvTime,
    t1.ProgStartTime, 
    t1.ProgEndTime, 
    t1.mbaid
FROM 
    (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by mbaid) as rId, * 
    from 
         mba
    ) t1, 
    (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by mapid) as rId, * 
    from 
         map
    ) t2
WHERE 
    t1.rId = t2.rId;a
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad925/6)

**[ROWNUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for your time but i do not want the join in accordance with row number. Row no's can change.

Comment: If you want to have non repeated advTime ti would be better if you do in you code which ever you are using. Then you original query is ok. There would be some way of achieving your needed output using sql but it wont be that efficient one.